# Batch file for loop fails to execute inside for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

the task is simple to take input from the file "input.txt" which contains the keyword that need to be replace in the source file "source.txt" and create the newfile with the name of the keyword. Could you please suggest what is wrong.

```
@echo off &setlocal
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "search=POP"
set "source=dev500_ABC_eu.env"
for /f %%a in (input.txt) do (
set "replace=%%a"
set "newfile=devga520_%replace%_eu.env"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
   set "line=%%i"
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
   echo(!line!
   endlocal
)>"%newfile%"
)
```

Here in the input.txt, suppose it has "PQR". So it should replace "POP" in the file with "PQR" and the new file shoud generate with the name  dev500_PQR_eu.env

```
Input file.txt
line 1 --> PQR
line 2 --> XYX
line 3 --> NOB
line 4 --> BOB
```

Output expected: 4 different files after replacing the character "ABC" with the input file text eg: whereevr "ABC" is there it should be replaced by PQR inside the dev500_ABC_eu.env and the newfile to be renamed with the text.

```
dev500_PQR_eu.env  --> replaced name and content as well by PQR.
dev500_XYX_eu.env 
dev500_NOB_eu.env 
dev500_BOB_eu.env
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you are using [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), you should not use interim variables `replace` and `newfile`, simply state `%%a` and `devga520_%%a_eu.env` instead, resp....

Comment: i have tried that but that too execute the first for and the result is only the last file get created after the second for execution. the execution of the first for loop should execute the second for loop for each variable in the input text file which is not happening. any suggestions. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
...
set "source=dev500_ABC_eu.env"
for /f %%a in (input.txt) do (set "replace=%%a")
set "newfile=devga520_%replace%_eu.env"
(
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
   set "line=%%i"
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
   echo(!line!
   endlocal
)
)>"%newfile%"
```

Please see `delayed expansion` items on SO for more info. Any `%var%` within a code block (parenthesised series of lines) will be replaced by the value of `var` at the time the block is first encountered.

You need to set `replace` outside of the block.

---

Your revision has clarified matters.

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "search=POP"
set "source=dev500_ABC_eu.env"
:: This is a replacement source file I used for testing...
set "source=c:q45416169_1.txt"
for /f %%a in (c:q45416169.txt) do (
 set "replace=%%a"
 set "newfile=devga520_%%a_eu.env"
 CALL DEL %%newfile%% >NUL 2>nul
 for /f "delims=" %%i in (%source%) do (
   set "line=%%i"
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   set "line=!line:%search%=%%a!"
   >>!newfile! echo(!line!
   endlocal
 )
)
```

I used a file named `q45416169.txt` containing your data for my testing.

I used a file named `q45416169_1.txt` containing some dummy text data for my testing.

I left the assignment of `replace` in the code, but it's now redundant.

Comment: Thanks Magoo. It works if the input file have only one keyword. When it has multiple keyword then it generates the file for the last one. I guess the replace function is executing first and it sets all the value & the replace function generates the file for the last keyword.
input.txt -->
PQR
XYZ
LOL

here in this case it generates file dev500_LOL_eu.env.

how can i make it to replace and generate files for all the input.

Comment: Add `"delims="` between the `/f` and the `%%` in the `for/f` statement to assign the entire line from the file to the variable, else only the first "token" is assigned (see `for /?|more` from the prompt for details)

Comment: the issue is different, the input file has one keyword per line. so actually it does replace all the keywords in input.txt and then for the last keyword which is on last line will be used for replace and generating the new file. The first loop get executed and it reach the last keyword and second loop takes the last keyword as input and generates the file.

I want to generate the file for all the keywords that are in input.txt, only one keyword per line. thanks for help

Comment: Please edit into your question some sample data showing what the original name and new name are expected to be

Comment: kindly let me know if its clear, thanks for your help.

Comment: Please could you review and suggest, that would be great help. thanks

Comment: Thanks Magoo, its work as expected. I have gone through your previous posts as well and learned a lot.